# An impolite commentator

Tags: word-usage

Sometimes we see some people writing  impolite comments on a YouTube video.  And sometimes they are secretly sent by companies, organisations or political entities who pay them to mislead viewers and make them turn against the Youtuber. Is there a formal or informal word describing those people?

Comment: Are they trolls?

Comment: ...or synonyms such as antagonist, stirrer etc.

Comment: Partially answered in this question about [people paid for bad product reviews](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/459838/191178). I would use a different term for when it's politically motivated. (See also [Term for a technique intended to draw criticism to an opposing view by overstating that view as your own (often emphatically)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/562719/191178).)

Comment: "Plant" could be appropriate for anyone who is injected into a situation to deliberately mislead.

Comment: Almost a mercenary.

Comment: internet moles, too.

Comment: A [joe job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_job) is when the fake messages apparently come from the _target_ of the attack, but I don't know if the term still applies to a fake _source._

Comment: More specifically, "paid troll" or "troll for hire", if they do this regularly for a living.